# Pyhon: A better way to run a function when an error occurs in the program?

Tags: python, error-handling, except

I created a big program that does a lot of different stuff. In this program, I added some error management but I would like to add management for critical errors which should start the `critical_error_function()`.

So basically, I've used :

```py
try :
    //some fabulous code
except :
    critical error(error_type)
```

But I am here to ask if a better way to do this...

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python try-except usage", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 1):

In Python exceptions are the intended way of error handling. Assuming you wrap your whole program in one try-except block, a better way would be to

- only try-except-wrap the lines that can generate exceptions instead of your complete program
- catch them with a specific exception such as `ValueError` or even your own custom exception instead of the blank `except` statement
- handle them appropriately. Handling could mean skipping this value, logging the error or calling your `critical_error_function`.

Comment: I need to put a `try` and `except` at any line that can cause errors?

Comment: You dont need to, but it is better style to be granular since then you can be more expressive/appropriate in your error handling as touched on in my answer.